# How to disable completion entirely for a specific shell command or alias?

Tags: shell, autocomplete

I have the following Bash alias which doesn't take any arguments.

```
alias b='cd ..'
```

Typing `b<space>` and then pressing `<tab>` brings up completion results for any paths in the current directory. How can I make it so that pressing `<tab>` does not trigger autocompletion of any kind? I have already tried `complete -r b` which didn't help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix Stackexchange. Why do you need to type `b<space><tab>`? Also, can you clarify if you want to disable autocompletion entirely, or just for commands starting with the letter 'b'?

Answer (score 1):

```
-bash-4.2$ alias b='cd ..'
-bash-4.2$ function nope() { :; }
-bash-4.2$ complete b -F nope
-bash-4.2$ b
```

So completing on the `nope` function appears to disable completion. Can we improve on this?

```
-bash-4.2$ alias b='cd ..'
-bash-4.2$ b
Display all 116 possibilities? (y or n)
-bash-4.2$ complete b -C :
-bash-4.2$ b
```

appears so; the "nothing" `:` command avoids the need to add a do-nothing function.